# Changing the Timeline Size

Tags: web-part, css, design, timeline, script-webpart

I have been struggling to find any info on this so I'm hoping somebody here can assist.

**End Goal:**
To have a page containing multiple web parts. One of which is a timeline without the list items being in view.

**Progress:**
I have created a custom list and have enabled the timeline in view and added this as a web part to a page. I then added the script editor web part and some CSS to hide the list items from appearing beneath the timeline. So good so far... The only issue now is that the timeline is dominating most of the page space. 
I have tried using F12 and finding the ID for the web part and tried to reduce the size however this isn't going as I hoped and I can only seem to resize individual parts such as each block on the timeline, font size for start and end date etc. I was wondering if there was a way to reduce the size of the whole thing just so it's clear there is content below this.

Using web part properties only allows me to change the frame size not the content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to play with the different types of pages that hold web parts to get a layout that works for you.

Using a Wiki or Web Part page you can select a layout and place the web part in a zone as it relates to the other web parts on your page to get the best results. Wiki Libraries can hold both wiki and web part pages as I the ease of use wiki pages have to offer where you can change the zone layout on the fly.

Web parts can be resized via the web part properties panel > Appearance > Height/Width. Otherwise they are set to fit the width and height of the zone they are in.